# How does journald get the very starting up message from kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, systemd-journald

I believe systemd-journald starts logging after the kernel starts up and need some time to set systems up like storage and network services.
But journal log has the kernel messages like dmesg has even they have real timestamp although kernel has no chance to recover real date/time from RTC in such early stage.
How does journald gets/shows kernel log messages?

Answer (score 2):

journald reads from `/dev/kmsg`, which contains a ring buffer of kernel logs.  `dmesg` accesses the same buffer.  I would not trust the "real date/time" to be super accurate for the initial kernel logs before journald has started.

Here is an example.  Both `dmesg` and `journalctl` show the same offset from boot

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmesg | head -n 1
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-131-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-108) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #147-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 14 17:07:22 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-131.147-generic 5.4.210)

root@ubuntu:~# journalctl --quiet -k -b --output short-monotonic | head -n 1
[    0.000000] ubuntu kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-131-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-108) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #147-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 14 17:07:22 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-131.147-generic 5.4.210)
```

However, the real time for the initial kernel log messages differs by over 9 seconds

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmesg --time-format iso | head -n 1
2022-11-02T20:29:35,000000+00:00 Linux version 5.4.0-131-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-108) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #147-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 14 17:07:22 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-131.147-generic 5.4.210)

root@ubuntu:~# journalctl --quiet -k -b --output short-iso-precise | head -n 1
2022-11-02T20:29:44.345820+0000 ubuntu kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-131-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-108) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #147-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 14 17:07:22 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-131.147-generic 5.4.210)
```

I doubt it is a coincidence that the "real time" difference for the initial kernel logs is close to the time it takes before journald is started.

```
[    8.335415] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
```

After journald has started the "real time" from `dmesg` and `journalctl` are very close, but not exactly the same.

Here is another example.  Write a new kernel log.

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo "THE TIME IS NOW: $(date --iso-8601=ns)" | tee /dev/kmsg
THE TIME IS NOW: 2022-11-02T22:17:22,986374849+00:00
```

Offsets remain identical.

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmesg | tail -n 1
[ 6467.404507] THE TIME IS NOW: 2022-11-02T22:17:22,986374849+00:00

root@ubuntu:~# journalctl --quiet -b -k --output short-monotonic | tail -n 1
[ 6467.404507] ubuntu unknown: THE TIME IS NOW: 2022-11-02T22:17:22,986374849+00:00
```

The "real time" is still slightly different.

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmesg --time-format iso | tail -n 1
2022-11-02T22:17:22,404507+00:00 THE TIME IS NOW: 2022-11-02T22:17:22,986374849+00:00

root@ubuntu:~# journalctl --quiet -b -k --output short-iso-precise | tail -n 1
2022-11-02T22:17:22.988718+0000 ubuntu unknown: THE TIME IS NOW: 2022-11-02T22:17:22,986374849+00:00
```

I believe `dmesg` is trying to [calculate the time](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/96ccdc00e1fcf1684f9734a189baf90e00ff0c9a/sys-utils/dmesg.c#L880) from the offset while `journalctl` is using the `__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` field [contained in the journal](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html#__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=).  I wish I was more certain.

Comment: Thanks! In short, journald gathers log from every services after it starts and merge the kernel log into the same journal log, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html#Description

Comment: Hmm, "If you get lost, go back to the basic"; thanks again and your result of investigation on accuracy of the 'real time' of logging is very interesting.